# save a variable within a structure

Tags: matlab, csv, save, structure

I need to save a bunch of scalar values inside a structure but the structure is nested within another structure. Basically, the main structure called `M` contains another structure called `P`, within `P` there are 10 other structures. The one I'm interested in is the 5th structure (let's call it `H`. Therefore I should be looking at `P(1,5)`). Within `H`, there is a structure called `X`, within `X` there are 150 scalar values. I would like to save these 150 values in csv format (let's name it beta.csv) so I can open in Excel later. Could someone please help?

Comment: If there are nested structs, use nested calls to STRUCT2CELL and at the final stage use CELL2MAT.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I  tried it but I'm sure because I did it incorrectly, it didn't seem to work. First, I did U = struct2cell(M). This gives me U with a number of cells. The cell I want is U{5,1}(1,5). In this is the X I want. Still not sure how to get to X.

Comment: U{5,1}(1,5)? Or U{5,1} and U(1,5) separately?